# Database design for products with multiple (flexible) variables

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value, webshop

There are alot of questions for my "problem" or "challenge". But none of them really fit my needs. Okay, here I go:

I want a database which holds variable attributes. Now I "hardcoded" them into the database (see image) as a columnname. See "color" and "size". But what if I want a new attribute? For example "model". I need to adjust the database and add a column. I don't want this.

[image]

Do you have any ideas? I'm thinking for a solution the past few months, and nothing good so far...

Comment: What about a colum in the attribute table called 'attributeType' which could hold 'color' or 'size'? Another column could then be 'attributeValue'.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware what if I have products that have both color and size. How would I do that?

Comment: One row in the products table could have multiple rows in the attributes table.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, I am aware of that, but how do you keep stock? For example, color red and size S we have 4 in stock, but red and size L we have 0

Comment: Stock could be an attribute like size or color, or you can put that column in the products table.

Comment: How do you keep stock of red size S  4 and red size L 8? Because when you do it in the products table, it will count for everything, and when you do it as an attribute, we dont know for what product specifically

Comment: Yes, you can have cases where product and attributes should be combined to make a stocked item. Clearly you would need a more advanced design for that... but that's beyond your question.

Comment: Sounds like you need the key value pair

Comment: @KIKOSoftware that's exactly what I am asking for. An idea for a more advanced design :)

Comment: @MIKE, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Or [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: Any more detailed answers please? Do not fully understand how I can make a better database design with EAV or key-value-pair?

Comment: Ignore that key-value thing. :-) Databases like this will become more and more complex. I cannot judge how far you want to take this, so it is difficult to create a more advanced design. I can give you a tip: Start by creating a separate table for 'stocked items', and for 'products', then let the 'stocked items' have attributes and each products can have multiple items (variations of the same product with different attributes).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I know right, been bashing my head on this question for months now... Can not get to a good solution. When each attribute is a different row, how can I keep stock then? That's actually the main question here.... :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [database schema for products attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194841/database-schema-for-products-attributes)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779252/entity-attribute-value-table-design/11972029#11972029

Comment: This forum is loaded with people asking similar questions; study them.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911659/designing-a-database-that-handles-inventory-tracking-with-product-variations/41915622

Answer (score 0):

So, after all the comments, this is what it now looks like. First the products table:

```
table: products
column: id
column: name
column: categoryId
```

Then the table with the stocked items. Each variation of a product should be respresented here:

```
table: items
column: id
column: productId
column: stock
column: price
```

Finally the table that contains the attributes of the stocked items:

```
tablet: attributes
column: id
column: itemId
column: type <color,size>
column: value <yellow,brown,large,small>
```

Comment: So are you saying, that Size S and color red, is productID 1 and size M and color red is productID 2? But then I get a whole bunch of records in my database. Would that not hurt performance?

Comment: No. A small red product is the same product as a medium red one, but it is a different stocked item. And you can also give it a different price. basically the `items` table creates a collection of attributes, and a stock number and price, for a certain product.

Comment: Okay, but how would you know the difference between a red S and a red M in stock list then? Because they have the same productId, so they do share the stock than also, right?

Comment: They will be represented in two different rows of the items table. They do not 'share' stock, at least that is what I assumed.

Comment: I don't think that's needed. Just go over it by yourself. Just remember: One stockable item can have multiple attributes and one product can have multiple stockable items. It's not really that difficult when you realize this.

Comment: I know what you mean, problem is, how do I keep track of stock, and how to retrieve it from database... :(

Comment: Just a warning, databases for webshops (I assume that is what this is for) tend to have dozens of tables and hundreds of columns. They get very complex very quick. That's why most shops use an existing solution.